# About creating pointer array in C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a BossClass , and I will have 5 entries of BossClass in future. I need them to be organized as an array (to be passed to other class), what would be the preferred method?

Here is some code for clarifying my question.

```
class BossClass 
{
    public:
        BossClass(int);
};
class MyClass 
{
    public:
        MyClass(BossClass*[5]);
};
MyClass someFunction()
{
    BossClass* bossClasses[5];                //[1]
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        // After some interactive input......
        bossClasses[i] = new BossClass(i);
    }
    return new MyClass(bossClasses);                //[2]
}
```

the problem in this code is, I cannot instantiate MyClass at [1] because the default constructor is not defined. **I cannot change the BossClass (but i can change MyClass) as a workaround handling the array of data.** What should I do here?

edit: corrected for some really logical errors. The compiler now calls for error with the message

> error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘BossClass**’ to ‘BossClass* [0]’ at [2]

And I am curious why array is not assignable to a pointer, as a further question.

Comment: _"I cannot instantiate MyClass at [1] because the default constructor is not defined"_ define one then.

Comment: Do you want pointers or values? You declare an array of `BossClass` but attempt to fill it with `BossClass*`.

Comment: Skip the array and use a `std::vector<BossClass>`. Oh, and skip all the `new`-ing. C++ isn't Java!

Comment: i am being hit by myth that vector is much slower than native arrays as some part of its data are the address. compare to native arrays, after allocation C++ just need some countable jump to access the next element. any mythbuster?

Answer (score 1):

Use standard container `std::vector<BossClass>` instead of the array.

For example

```
#include <vector>

//...

class BossClass 
{
    public:
        BossClass(int);
};

class MyClass 
{
    public:
        MyClass( const std::vector<BossClass> & );
};
MyClass * someFunction()
{
    std::vector<BossClass> bossClasses;
    bossClasses.reserve( 5 );

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // After some interactive input......
        bossClasses.emplace_back( i );
    }

    return new MyClass( bossClassese );
}
```

Also you can add one more constructor in class MyClass

```
        MyClass( std::vector<BossClass> && );
```

and write in the function

```
    return new MyClass( std::move( bossClassese ) );
```

Comment: but would it causes some performance problem? since memory needed for MyClass is pretty much the same and I think a pre-defined malloc is better than vector which trades speed with ability to resize

Comment: @orb  As i pointed out in my answer you can move the vector around among functions. Also As I showed you can use method reserve to reserve enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<BossClass>);
};

MyClass someFunction()
{
    std::vector<BossClass>   bossClasses;                //[1]
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        // After some interactive input......
        bossClasses.push_back(BossClass(i));
    }
   return MyClass(bossClasses);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a *"working"* modified snippet:

```
class BossClass 
{
    public:
        BossClass() = default;
        BossClass(int) { }
};
class MyClass 
{
    public:
        MyClass(BossClass*[5]) { }
};
MyClass* someFunction()
{
    BossClass* bossClasses[5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        bossClasses[i] = new BossClass(i);
    }
    return new MyClass(bossClasses);
}
```

**However**, remember that C++ is **not** Java (nor C#). It does not have garbage collector, hence the above code will not clean up all those resources created with `new` allocator. Much, much better idea for you is to use smart pointers instead of the raw ones. For further information and a quick "how to", you can check out [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).